# How to get this selection tool into Operation Dashboard?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, operations-dashboard

How to get this selection tool over the Operation Dashboard map ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **Select** widget appears when you create a **Layer Action** which originates in the map. For an example, I have a map and a list of features.

[image: map with feature list]

If I then go to **Configure** on the map, and select the **Layer Actions** tab, I can add a **Filter** action that applies to the list.

[image: map layer action]

The widget is now visible in the map, and selecting features performs the action which I specified.

[image: filter dashboard]

Comment: thanks for your reply with details. but i did that before and it doesn't come to the map. do you think there are something else i missed ? like Operation dashboard version !

Comment: Are you on ArcGIS Online, or Portal?

Comment: I am using Portal

Comment: And what version?